# Netsuite: Access non-transaction based saved searches in workflow

Tags: transactions, workflow, netsuite

Good morning.

I am editing a transaction based workflow that sends an email out to customers. This works fine, but it needs to have a decision based on a custom features based saved search. The search works fine and I can see the results I want in the search.

The issue is the Saved Search Conditions in the Action in the Workflow does not show the search because it is not Transaction based. I cannot make the search Transaction based as the record type is not a Transaction.

Is there any way to access this saved search through a transaction based workflow?

Thank you!

Comment: What relationship does the 'custom features' have with the transactions you need to send emails from?  Depending on what it is, you may be able to re-write the search as a transaction search using joins to access your custom feature from the search.  From [SuiteAnswer 46202](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/46202/kw/saved%20search%20condition) "by design, workflow will only get the saved searches of the same record type that was created before it"

Comment: There is a "switch" of sorts in the Custom Features Record Type that determines the type of email template to send. If it is on, send Template A, if not, Template B. The Features record type is a custom record type that assists in setting global type features for other record types to read from.

Comment: I might have to do this in a workflow action script which is a new thing for me. Luckily, I have resources in office to assist.